# What is the difference between a "smart client application" and "rich Internet application"?

Tags: ria, rich-internet-application, smartclient

What is the difference between "smart client application" and "rich Internet application"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article explains it very well:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7409/Building-Smart-Client-using-NET

[image: Venn diagram with smart clients features]